# Content script not receiving message when multiple tabs are open

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm working on a chrome extension. I've added buttons on a one page of a site. When clicked, they create a tab and open another page of the site. On the newly created page i inject some script.

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript(
  newTab.id,
  {
    file: 'script-to-be-injected.js',
  },
)
```

This script performs some actions on newly created page and those actions redirect to another page. Now when this redirected page is loaded. As my previously injected script is removed, I send a message from content script to this page using a specific port and this page also injects script into this page. Now this newly injected script gets some info from this page and closes the redirected page and send message to my first page (the page where i opened other pages). The problem i'm currently facing is message is not being received on first page. If i don't close the redirected page i can see the message being console'd on redirected page as its also listening to messages on this port.
Here's the code of background script of the last part

```
port.onMessage.addListener(({ message }, sender) => {
  if(message === 'GET_DETAIL_FROM_REDIRECTION_PAGE') {
    chrome.tabs.query({ url: REDIRECTED_PAGE_URL }, ([tab]) => {
      chrome.tabs.executeScript(
        tab.id,
        {
          file: 'some-script.js',
        },
        () => {
          chrome.tabs.remove(tab.id, () => {
            console.log('sending message to port');
            port.postMessage({ message: 'GOT_INFO' });
          });
        }
      )
    });
  }

  return true;
});
```

Content script

```
const port = chrome.runtime.connect(null, { name: PORT_NAME });

if (port.name) {
  if (window.location.href === REDIRECTION_PAGE) {
    port.postMessage({ message: 'GET_INFO' });
  } else if (window.origin === TARGET_SITE) {
    port.onMessage.addListener(({ message }) => {
      console.log({ message });
      if (message === 'GOT_INFO') {
      // perform other actions
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Please let me know if any other part of the code is required. Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like you may be closing the page too soon so the messaging doesn't get enough time as it's asynchronous.

Comment: You can see i `postMessage` inside callback of `chrome.tabs.remove`

Comment: Shoudn't all the listeners of the port receive the message?

Comment: I don't "see" anything from the posted fragment of code because it doesn't show me the entire timeline of what happens and the guess above is the only thing I can infer from the verbal description of the process.

Comment: It's hard for me to recreate the sequence of events just by looking at the code. Let's tackle this from a different angle: 1) why are you using `port` and not simple messaging? 2) why chrome.tabs.query instead of using port.sender.tab.id or even storing the id in a variable?

Comment: Yes i had solved it yesterday using simple messaging. I used ports as i was using ports for another task as well. Will post the solution.